# Why are jasmine-jquery event spies inconsistent?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, jasmine-jquery

Why does the same test case, when run a second time, fail?

## Setup

```
var element, elementClickSpy;
beforeEach(function() {
    element = angular.element('<div id="some-element"></div>');
    $('body').append(element);
    elementClickSpy = spyOnEvent('#some-element', 'click');
});
```

## Case 1

The first case works as expected.

```
it('should work', function() {
    expect(elementClickSpy).not.toHaveBeenTriggered();
    element.click();
    expect(elementClickSpy).toHaveBeenTriggered();
});
```

## Case 2 (Identical to Case 1)

The second assertion fails for some reason even though the case is an *exact* copy of the first case.

```
it('should work again', function() {
    expect(elementClickSpy).not.toHaveBeenTriggered();
    element.click();
    expect(elementClickSpy).toHaveBeenTriggered();
});
```

Comment: In the second test case, does it fail on the first or second assertion? (I'm wondering if the wrong element is getting spied on in your `beforeEach`, e.g. the body isn't getting cleaned up after each test)

Comment: Only the second assertion is failing. Weird huh? So if the body isn't getting clean up then I would expect the first expectation to fail.

Comment: Perhaps. What's in the `...` of your `spyOnEvent` call?

Comment: A jquery selector the id of the element created. '#id-of-element'

Comment: You might try hooking to the element directly, e.g. `spyOnEvent(element, 'click')`, or try cleaning up the body in an afterEach: `$('body').html('')` or something similar. It may be returning a new spy on the *old* element, so then you click the new one and the spy doesn't fire.

Comment: `spyOnEvent(element, 'click')` seems to work even though the [documentation](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#event-spies) makes no mention of being able to do that. Would you mind adding that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize what we found in the comments above, it seems as though the DOM isn't getting cleaned up between tests. Because you're using an ID `#some-element` to bind to the click handler, the second test is spying on the first element, but you're clicking on the new one.

You can either:

1. Spy on exactly the element you're concerned with: `spyOnEvent(element, 'click')` or
2. Clean up the DOM between tests (by `.remove()`ing the button, or clearing the body's HTML)

Comment: Thanks. It does in fact appear that karma or jasmine or something is not resetting the dom after each test. I added some code in the beforeEach to do this manually.